# What is the correct way to use 'elder, eldest'? Please tell me the sequence with regard to 5 sisters?

Tags: word-usage

There are five sisters, 1-eldest, 2-elder, 3-older/younger, 4-youngest, 5-youngest.

What is the correct way to use 'elder, eldest'? Please tell me the sequence in between these 5 sisters.

Comment: Can you please provide more context or information about what you don't understand? At present your question does not appear to make much sense. For instance, why do you say 'elder' in one place, but 'older' somewhere else? Why do you say '4' is the youngest?

Comment: Who are these sisters?  Are they real?

Comment: _Elder_ is a comparative, not a place in the family.  The eldest sister has four _younger sisters_, the youngest has four _elder sisters_. The third sister could call herself the _middle sister_ as there are an odd number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of describing these. I would probably say eldest, second eldest, middle, second youngest, youngest, following each with 'of five sisters'.

Answer (score 3):

"Elder" is the comparative.  "Eldest" is the superlative.

Hence, 1 is the oldest, and 5 is the youngest, if you take all five as a group.  It would also make sense to say that of 3, 4, and 5, 3 is the eldest.  It depends on the group.

2 is the elder if compared to 3, 4, or 5, but if compared to 1, 1 is the elder.  4 is the younger if compared to 1,2, or 3, but the elder if compared to 5.  To talk about the elder, you need a set of two.

Taking all five as a group, it would be logical to say that 1 is the oldest, 2 the second oldest, 3 the middle, 4 the second youngest, and 5 the youngest.

Answer (score 0):

English doesn't distinguish titles for sisters like this.

Certainly, the "1 is the oldest".

We would say that "2 is older than 3" and "2 is younger than 1"

We would say that "2 is the second oldest sister"

We could say that "3 is the middle sister".

"4 is the second youngest" and "5 is the youngest sister".

However such large families are now very rare.  So this situation doesn't come up very often.